# Sharing downloaded games between two Wii-U consoles we own

Tags: wii-u, mario-kart-8

We have a wii u upstairs, and just recently bought one for the basement.  We have several downloaded versions on the upstairs box already, specifically Mario Kart 8.  Are we able to play that game in the basement as well, without paying full price for it again?  (I wish now that just purchased the hard copy as that could have been transferred between consoles when needed.)

Comment: Short answer: nope.  Digital copies are locked to their consoles.

Comment: No, if you purchased the game online, the copy is locked to the console you originally downloaded it on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't have one nintendo ID [registered to multiple consoles.](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2210/~/can-i-log-into-my-nintendo-network-id-on-a-different-system%3F)

> Once a Nintendo Network ID has been associated to a Wii U, it can only
>   be used with that same Wii U. There is not currently an option within
>   the system that will allow you to transfer the Nintendo Network
>   account from one Wii U to another.

They do have a support link to do that sort of transfer on the site, but I doubt they would be willing to go back and forth multiple times.

Comment: When my Wii-U got hit with a power surge, Nintendo was able to transfer the licensing to my new console but informed me that this was a one-way transfer. That was back around the time it first came out, but I doubt things have changed.

Comment: I have heard some rumors that they are moving towards a more sane policy of tying games to NNID, instead of console, but nothing concrete yet.